# How to call executable with file list, two at a time?

Tags: bash, shell

I have an operation `f` that processes arguments in this way:

```
f(f(f(a,b),c),d)...
```

`f` is a program, and the arguments are filenames. It is typically called like this:

```
f a b | f - c | f - d > result
```

Is there a short bash way to make this call easier? I have a list of
files, say `*.txt`, and I'd like to call `f` on those files, something
like

```
callpairs(f, *.txt) > result
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you two versions in pure bash.  Both use array slicing to get groups of arguments (e.g. `"${@:1:3}"` gives the first three arguments).  Both also maintain quoting on the file arguments (so you can use them on e.g. files with spaces in the name), but not on the command itself (so you could use e.g. `callpairs "sort -f" file1 file2 file3` and it'd treat `-f` as an option to the sort command, not part of the commandname).

First, here's a recursive version:

```
#!/bin/bash

args=$#
if [ $args -lt 3 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 command file1 file2 [file3 ...]" >&2
    exit 1
elif [ $args -eq 3 ]; then
    $1 "$2" "$3"
else
    "$0" "${@:1:$args-1}" | $1 - "${!args}"
fi
```

And here's a version that builds entire command pipeline as a string, then `eval`s it:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 command file1 file2 [file3 ...]" >&2
    exit 1
fi

cmd="$(printf "%s %q %q" "${@:1:3}")"
for file in "${@:4}"; do
    cmd+="$(printf " | %s - %q" "$1" "$file")"
done

eval "$cmd"
```

A bit of a warning here: `eval` has a well-deserved reputation for causing bugs if you don't get your quoting and escaping just right. I *think* I got it right here (I tested with a file with spaces in the name, and another named `a$(halt).txt` -- just the sort of things to trigger eval bugs), but there's no absolute guarantee. (BTW, the perl version would fail these tests.)

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I wrote this little perl script `callpairs` that does it:

```
my ($exe, @args) = @ARGV;
if (!defined $exe || !defined $ARGV[0] || !defined $ARGV[1]) {
  die;
}
my $f1 = shift @args;
my $f2 = shift @args;
my $cmd = "$exe $f1 $f2";
while (scalar @args) {
  my $f = shift @args;
  $cmd .= " | $exe - $f";
}
print "$cmd\n";
```

It can be called like this:

```
callpairs f *.txt | bash
```